# Form Validation - Clean Method Interfering with PATCH Requests

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a form that looks like this:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    error_messages = {
            'duplicate_name': 'A backup contact with that name already exists for this location',
            'missing_location': 'No location supplied.'
    }

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'notification_preference', 'email', 'phone')
        model = Contact
········
    def clean_name(self):
        # FIXME: Location validation shouldn't be happening here, but it's difficult to get
        # form fields for foreign key relationships to play nicely with Tastypie
        print dir(self)
        if 'location' in self.data:
            location = Location.objects.get(pk=self.uri_to_pk(self.data['location']))
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['missing_location'])

        # No duplicate names in a given location
        if 'name' in self.cleaned_data and Contact.objects.filter(name=self.cleaned_data['name'], location=location).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_name'])

        return self.cleaned_data
```

I'm using it to validate calls to my TastyPie API. The `clean_name` method is meant to prevent POST requests from happening if they post a contact with the same name to the same location. This works perfectly as long as I'm making a POST request.

If I make a PATCH however, changing, say, the email and phone field on an already existent contact, the `clean_name` logic is still fired. Since the name already exists for a given location, it raises a validation error.

Should I be overriding something other than `clean_name`? Can I change the way PATCH works so it ignores certain validations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're checking values between fields, I'd recommend implementing a general `def clean(self, data)` that checks the values don't conflict.

Regarding checking for duplicates, I'd advise you to use an `.exclude(pk=instance.pk)` in your `exists()` queryset to prevent mistakenly detecting an update the the model as a duplicate.  Looking at the [tastypie validation source](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/validation.py), it adds the appropriate `self.instance` for the object being updated.

```
qs = Contact.objects.filter(name=self.cleaned_data.get('name', ''), location=location)
if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
    qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
if qs.exists():
    raise forms.ValidationError(...)
```